# Variable not carrying over to all libraries when using POST

Tags: php

Whenever I declare a variable inside a library like:

```
$Money="123";
```

The variable carries over to my other libraries like print page and export pdf.

However when I declare a variable using Post like:

```
$Money=$Post_["moneyNumber"];
```

My other libraries pull a null value. What can I do to carry on the variable? I need to be able to send the variable from a form input.

Comment: Be more consistent with case. It's good practice to generally use lowercase for variable names, element names etc. and uppercase for superglobals, so `$money = $_POST["moneynumber"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Money=$Post_("moneyNumber");
```

is incorrect. You're using camel case for `Post` which should be all uppercase (see note about superglobals) and round brackets which should be square brackets, and you've a misplaced underscore also.

use

```
$Money=$_POST["moneyNumber"];
```

Also make sure your form is using a POST method, along with its element having a name attribute of `name="moneyNumber"`

Sidenote: "moneyNumber" is not the same as "moneynumber". Variables are case-sensitive, should that be the case in the rest of your *unshown* code. Same thing goes for `$Money`. So, if you're using `$money` elsewhere, then that is a probability.

`$_POST` is a superglobal:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit:**

If you're trying to carry variables over more than two pages via POST, then that won't work. You will need to use sessions for this.

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
- http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_2.htm

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it to mean square brackets. The variable works on the page of the onaction=index.php. However, when I click the button to print the page which uses another library, it pulls a null value for the variable.

Comment: @ABCCompany I answered for what you posted for code. You're going to have to update your question including full code. Don't overwrite your existing question but as an Edit under it. Otherwise, people stand at downvoting my answer.